# Help understanding a property of modulus

Tags: real-analysis

If it is given that $|b|>1$ and $|ab|=1$

can someone please explain what should be the value of $|a|$ ?

Comment: Note that $|ab|=|a|\cdot |b|$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  It is  given that $|a|<1$, I am unable to understand why

Comment: If you had $|a|\ge1$, then $|ab|=|a|\cdot |b|\ge |b|>1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of basic properties of $|\cdot|$ is that $$|ab|=|a||b|,$$
so we can write $$1=|ab|=|a||b|.$$ Clearly $b\ne 0$. Then we divide both parts by $|b|$:
$$|a|=\frac{1}{|b|}.$$
We know that $|b|>1$, then (divide by $|b|$) $$\frac{1}{|b|}<1,$$
hence $$|a|<1.$$